# Como hacer un condicional para validar si el elemento esta. Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Un favor . Necesito saber como puedo hacer para que valide que el elemento este. ya que intente con un if y un equals y no me funciono .

```
    String campo="SedesDatagrid_rc_0_3";

    checkbox.findElement(By.id(campo)).click();
```

Debe validar si existe ese campo y si existe pues ejecute tal codigo, y si no exste , pues ejecute otro codigo

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Se puede realizar de esta forma usando `WebDriver`, diferente de 0 determina que existe el elemento:

```
  Boolean existeElemento = driver.findElements(By.id(campo)).size() != 0
```

También puedes buscar en una lista de elementos:

```
List<WebElement> dynamicElement = driver.findElements(By.id(<"id de elemento">));

if(dynamicElement.size() != 0){
  System.out.println("Existe elemento");
}else{//0, elemento no esta presente.
   System.out.println("Elemento no existe");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés utilizar la siguiente sentencia:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed();
```

Comment: Creo que te falta algo de contextualización, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)